# How to fix Seriate and Lodash vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, npm, lodash

For my project I have one package used, Seriate.

`npm install seriate`

However running this gives the following result:

> found 17 vulnerabilities (9 low, 1 moderate, 7 high)

I ran `npm audit` and `npm audit fix` yet nothing. I have also looked into the dependencies, Lodash seems to have a security issue (supposedly fixed at 4.17.11).

How can I fix these? I have tried to update lodash like so: `npm install lodash@4.17.11` however that didn't work either.

Also is this something to worry about, it runs from a local server which is secure in itself?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security issues spotted by `npm audit` can't be fixed automatically (ie by changing packages versions to equivalent secure versions), they require manual review, thus can't be fixed simply by `npm audit fix`. `npm audit fix --force` would be an option (caution: introduces breaking changes!) but for me that fixed none of the 17 issues.

When installing the current version of `seriate`, `lodash@4.7.11` is already required/installed so `npm i lodash@4.7.11` won't change anything.

Whether these issues are dangerous or not in your case would really require an investigation from your part. Note that it's not because `lodash` is insecure that using `lodash` is - only in certain cases, only in certain machines, only for certain functions, etc. Start by reading the NPM advisories related to the security issues (like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/782)).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, I don't use the command specified in your link

Comment: I've posted an [issue](https://github.com/LeanKit-Labs/seriate/issues/90) to Seriate's github

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Nino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8186898/nino-filiu) `npm audit` won't resolve Lodash security vulnerabilities automatically.

- **Security vulnerabilities found requiring manual review**

If security vulnerabilities are found, but no patches are available, the audit report will provide information about the vulnerability so you can investigate further.
[snapshot of sample audit report is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrA6x.jpg)

- To address the vulnerability, you can

  1. Check for mitigating factors
  2. Update dependent packages if a fix exists
  3. Fix the vulnerability

***Check for mitigating factors***

Review the security advisory in the “More info” field for mitigating factors that may allow you to continue using the package with the vulnerability in limited cases. For example, the vulnerability may only exist when the code is used on specific operating systems, or when a specific function is called.

***Update dependent packages if a fix exists***

If a fix exists but packages that depend on the package with the vulnerability have not been updated to include the fixed version, you may want to open a pull or merge request on the dependent package repository to use the fixed version.

1. To find the package that must be updated, check the “Path” field for the location of the package with the vulnerability, then check for the package that depends on it. For example, if the path to the vulnerability is **@package-name > dependent-package > package-with-vulnerability**, you will need to update **dependent-package**.
2. On the **npm public registry**, find the dependent package and navigate to its repository. For more information on finding packages, see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/searching-for-and-choosing-packages-to-download)
3. In the dependent package repository, open a pull or merge request to update the version of the vulnerable package to a version with a fix.
4. Once the pull or merge request is merged and the package has been updated in the npm public registry, update your copy of the package with `npm update`

***Fix the vulnerability***

If a fix does not exist, you may want to suggest changes that address the vulnerability to the package maintainer in a pull or merge request on the package repository.

1. Check the “Path” field for the location of the vulnerability.
2. On the npm public registry, find the package with the vulnerability. For more information on finding packages, see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/searching-for-and-choosing-packages-to-download)
3. In the package repository, open a pull or merge request to make the fix on the package repository.
4. Once the fix is merged and the package has been updated in the npm public registry, update your copy of the package that depends on the package with the fix.